# How to store user specific data in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, store

I have a react app where I am consuming APIs and working on its response data. That data will be different for different users based upon its usage. Right now what I am doing is I am storing that data into redux store and using it on diff components.

For example, take a scenario, user logged in to application, on successful login I will get auth token.I am storing it in redux store. Then on next page user will do customer search. For that, user will type some text in textbox and click on search button. On search button click I am calling search API with auth token which I got on login API success. Now I am storing that search result in store so that I can use that search result on diff pages on UI. My confusion is that whatever data I am storing in store, will it be diff for diff users or same. Becasue multiple users will access the application at same time and they may perform the search for diff charecters.  I dont want it to be same.

If redux is not needed then what is alternative to store user specific data and should not create ambiguity to other users. How can I store data other that redux store and use it on different components for display purposes.

Comment: Any data in JavaScript is store in the user's browser, it's not shared between users unless you explicitly made the app send the data back and forth with a server.

Comment: If security is not an issue, how about going with localStorage and sessionStorage. [local VS session storage](https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/)

Comment: User specific data like recent search history, preferences can be easily stored in local or session storage of the browser.

Comment: @EmileBergeron so does it mean that data in the store is user specific and each user will have its own store data?

Comment: @Sallu How is that any different than storing the data in a redux store? After all its a SPA... did you read the post?

Comment: @Sallu I think data is huge and if I store it in local then memory issue may occur on server.

Comment: @Nilesh When the user searches, and the server returns the search result then these results will be unique to the user searching because there is no change in the data in the database. Every request will be different.

Comment: @Nilesh each user has its own browser. React, Redux etc are JavaScript libs that run in the browser completely separated from each other users.

Comment: @Baruch so does it mean that I can keep using redux store and data in it will be different as per different users.

Comment: @Nilesh Yes, exactly. But remember, data stored in Redux does not persist from refresh to refresh.

Comment: Oh! I did not know that store is user specific. Thanks Baruch and Emile Bergeron.

Comment: @Baruch Thank you  very very much for this help.

Comment: @EmileBergeron thank you very much for clarification.